# Prevent some content from being edited in contenteditable td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a `td` in a table with `contenteditable="true"`. Inside the `td` I have a `span` with some contents. I want to make the `td` editable except this `span`. How can I do that?

```
<td colspan="4" contenteditable="true">
  <span class='notForEdit'><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span>
</td>
```

Comment: Not possible in HTML directly. I'm sure you could hack together some really ugly solution to keep that string at the start of the `contenteditable` content, but it would be a maintenance nightmare. It's far simpler to take the `contenteditable` off the `td`, and just have that `span` before another `div` which holds the `contenteditable` data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do this like that :

```
<td colspan="4">
  <span contenteditable="true">
    editable test
  </span >
  <span contenteditable="false"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span>
  <span contenteditable="true">
    more editable test
  </span >
</td>
```

Comment: It's not really necessary to define the `contenteditable="false"` as long as the attribute isn't used on the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do things like this.

```css
td{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
p{
float:left;
padding:0.1em;
}
```

```html
<td>
<p contenteditable="true">
This is a paragraph annd is editable. 
</p>
<p>A solid text.</p>
<p contenteditable="true">
next stuff. 
</p>
</td>
```